# Maximizing the Likelihood function

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, log-likelihood

I want to maximize the likelihood function in respect the theta parameter. The likelihood function is defined as:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def prloglik(theta,n,r):
    N=theta;k=len(n)
    ar1=np.sum(np.log(np.array(range(N))+1))
    ar2=np.sum(n)*np.log(np.sum(n)/(k*N))
    ar3=(k*N-np.sum(n))*np.log(1-(np.sum(n))/(k*N))
    par=np.sum(np.log(np.array(range(N-r))+1))

    return(-(ar1+ar2+ar3-par))
```

I use:

```
res=minimize(prloglik,1000,method='BFGS',args=(nn,962))
```

Where `nn` is a numpy array. And I get this error:

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try adding some print statements? The parameter arguments to the function are passed as an array, so theta starts as [1000]. Also, does the parameter have to be an integer? I believe scipy.optimize.minimize doesn't allow this, as it requires floating point args to get derivatives, etc.

Comment: Ok, I'm new to the Python I mainly use R, when you say print statements what do you mean?

Comment: You can add print(theta, n, r) at the top of your function to show what's being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution just instead of:

```
     np.sum(np.log(np.array(range(N))+1))
```

I put

```
    math.lgamma(N+1)
```

and instead of

```
    np.sum(np.log(np.array(range(N-r))+1))
```

I put

```
   math.lgamma((N-r)+1)
```

But it's the same thing, the logarithm of the factorial N and N-r respectively, I don't get why it doesn't accept the way I had it previously.

Comment: Because N is an array, not a scalar